# Generalizing the Policy for Model-based reinforcement learning algorithm with large state and action spaces

Tags: machine-learning, policy, reinforcement-learning, generalization

I am using a model-based single agent reinforcement learning approach for autonomous flight.

In this project I used a simulator to collect training data (state , action , ending state) so that a `Locally Weighted Linear Regression` algorithm can learn the `MODEL`.

The `STATE` is defined by a vector : `[Pitch , Yaw , Roll , Acceleration]` to define the position of the drone in space.
When given to the `POLICY` It has one other feature `[WantedTrajectory]`

The `ACTION` is defined by a vector too : `[PowerOfMotor1 , PowerOfMotor2 , PowerOfMotor3 , PowerOfMotor4]`

The `REWARD` is calculated depending on the accuracy of the trajectory taken: given a starting spacial state , a wanted trajectory and the ending spacial state the closer is the trajectory actually taken to the one wanted the less negative the reward is.

The algorithm for `policy iteration` is the following :

```
start from a state S0

loop    

         1) select the best action according to the Policy

         2) use LWLR to find the ending state

         3) calculate reward

         4) update generalized V function



endloop;
```

This way the action taken depends also on the trajectory wanted (choosed by the user) , the agent autonomously choose the power of the 4 motors (Trying to take the wanted trajectory and have a bigger , less negative , reward) and the policy is dynamic since It depends on the value function which is updated.

The only problem is that choosing the `POLICY` as follows (S = Pitch , Yaw , Roll , Acceleration , WantedTrajectory):

```
π(S) = argmax_a ( V( LWLR(S,a) ) )
```

(So between all the actions the one that from this state will lead the agent in the state with the biggest Value) costs a lot in terms of computation since the action space is very large.

Is there a way to generalize a POLOCY depending on an already generalized VALUE FUNCTION ?

Comment: Why don't you use action discretization? and Function approximation for the states would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I think that actor-critic methods using policy gradient will be useful to you.

In that case, you use a paremetrized policy which is adjusted based on an objetive function based on your value function. There are some further improvements such as using advantage functions, etc.

David Silver made a nice video that you may find useful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHZVXao4qXs&index=7&list=PL5X3mDkKaJrL42i_jhE4N-p6E2Ol62Ofa